# Catch NoNullAllowedException in a DGV for a specific column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 3 columns (ID, Name, Birthday) (where nulls are not allowed) in a dgv.When i dont put in a Name i want to pop up a msgbox "Please put in a Name" but dont know how to catch an error in a specific row. 
At the moment when i dont put in something there i get a error message and after pressing OK the dataset (data in the row) are deleted. I dont want that either. 
What i tried was:

```
Private Sub DataGridView_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.DataError
If Not e.Exception Is Nothing AndAlso _
e.Context = DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit Then
MessageBox.Show(DataGridView.Columns.IndexOf & "a value must be inserted")
End If
End Sub
```

Of course Columns.IndexOf is nonsense but there was no "name" method. But something in this direction could be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `Try...Catch..` statement. This will catch your error, and you can put a message box as the catch.

Comment: Hi! I did that and i was trying "DataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText" to get the header of the column with the error. But when i leave the row in column 5 and the error is in column 1 DataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText gives me the column header of column 5 instead of the one where the error occured. It looks like it always gives me the header of the selected column. Anyone who knows how i can get the header of the column with where the error is?

Comment: Did you put the `Try..Catch..` around the whole pice of code? It should not matter what column is selected.